# Working with generic function

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, generics, alamofire

I have the following mapping class. You will see that I use `ObjectMapper` and `RealmSwift` because I want to save the class also in Realm.

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import RealmSwift

class LoginResponse: Object,Mappable {

    dynamic var status: Int = 0
    dynamic var client: LoginData!

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        client <- map["client"]
        status <- map["status"]
    }
}
```

Now what I have the following function:

```
  public func login(email: String, password: String) -> LoginResponse {
        let request = RestoryApiRequest.login(email, password: password)
        return request.toObjectMapper()
    }
```

Below you see the APIRequest class:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import RealmSwift


struct ApiRequest {
    let method: Alamofire.Method
    let path: String
    let parameters: [String: AnyObject]?
    let uiRealm = try! Realm()


    init(method: Alamofire.Method = .GET, path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil) {
        self.method = method
        self.path = "webservice/abc123/client/\(path)"

        self.parameters = parameters
    }

    func toObjectMapper<T: Mappable>() -> Object {
        let alomofireApiRequest = AlamofireApiRequest(apiRequest: self)
        Alamofire.request(alomofireApiRequest)
            .responseObject("") { (response: Response<T, NSError>) in
                let parsedObject = response.result.value as! Object
                try! self.uiRealm.write({ () -> Void in

                    self.uiRealm.add(parsedObject)
                })

               return parsedObject
        }
    }
}
```

Lik you see I want to pass the Mappable class in and give the Object class back. But this gives the following compiler errors:

```
Generic parameter 'T' is not used in function signature

Unexpected non-void return value in void function
```

Can someone help me with this? If you need more info please ask!

Comment: first error is clear enough from the message. how the compiler could recognise what is T? you should have parameter and / or return value with type related to T. The second one is because you return parseObject  and you should not.  Response<T, NSError> in is equivalent of Response<T, NSError>->Void in ... so you should return nothing from the closure

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the complete code, as the compile errors said, there are two issues, one for 'T' is not used in your function, the other for no return in your function.

The fix should similar to this:

```
    // No Return, the result is in the completion block.
func toObjectMapper<T: Mappable>(completion: (T)->Void) {
    let alomofireApiRequest = AlamofireApiRequest(apiRequest: self)
    Alamofire.request(alomofireApiRequest)
        .responseObject("") { (response: Response<T, NSError>) in

            // The parsedObject is already of class T
            let parsedObject = response.result.value
            try! self.uiRealm.write({ () -> Void in

                self.uiRealm.add(parsedObject)
            })

            completion(parsedObject)
    }
}
```